# syntax error at or near "http" in INSERT statement (sql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Getting error when trying to RUN:

```
INSERT INTO dtb_order VALUES (
    14,1920,NULL,
    'テスト',NULL,'03','6302','0215',NULL,NULL,NULL,'160','0023',NULL,0,13,
    '新宿区西新宿','セントラルパークタワー・ラ・トゥール',6,
    '1972-09-02 00:00:00',NULL,3150,0,1,500,0,0,0,0,150,3650,3650,8,
    'NP後払い',NULL,9000,'2013-09-12 18:42:56',
    '2013-09-23 19:42:22',NULL,NULL,10,1,NULL,
    'a:2:{s:5:\"title\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:32:\"NP後払いでのお支払情報\";s:5:\"value\";b:1;}s:3:\"msg\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:15:\"ご注意事項\";s:5:\"value\";s:388:\"株式会社ネットxxxションズより、商品とは別に郵送されます。\n主要コンビニ・銀行・郵便局でお支払いできますので、商品の到着を確認してから、\nお支払いをお願いいたします。\nNP後払いの詳しいご案内はこちら⇒ <a href=\'http://np-someurl.jp/about/\' target=\'_blank\'>http://np-someurl.jp/about/</a>\n\";}}',
    NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
);
```

Error message:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "http"
LINE 1: ...ます。\nNP後払いの詳しいご案内はこちら⇒ <a href=\'http://np-...
                                                             ^
```

Tried `http:\/\/np-...` no luck.

++++++++

is there other way except $$ (my string with http) $$, because I have almost 200 000 INSERTs and only some of them have http://,  I just want to fix "http://" with substitution by vim or something like that, not manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `\'` to `"` & `\"` to `"` did the trick.

VIM

```
:%s/\\'/"/gc

:%s/\\"/"/gc
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not show the whole command. My guess is that it is not properly escaped. Use dollar quoting `$$` in instead of single quotes so it is not necessary to escape single quotes in the string. Also use escape string `E` syntax to have the new lines `\n`

```
E$$a:2:{s:5:"title";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:32:"NP後払いでのお支払情報";s:5:"value";b:1;}s:3:"msg";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:15:"ご注意事項";s:5:"value";s:388:"株式会社ネットxxxションズより、商品とは別に郵送されます。\n主要コンビニ・銀行・郵便局でお支払いできますので、商品の到着を確認してから、\nお支払いをお願いいたします。\nNP後払いの詳しいご案内はこちら⇒ <a href='http://np-someurl.jp/about/' target='_blank'>http://np-someurl.jp/about/</a>\n";}}$$,
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: Thank you.
I edited my question. Can you check it again, please.

Comment: Thank you man.
I change \n => E\n, still getting the same error.

With $$ it does work, but without $$ it doesn't. Maybe, there is other way? cuz 200 000 lines don't wanna change it manually :)

Thank you for your help

Comment: @whitesiroi if you want to import such a large dataset, you *may* want to set `standard_conforming_strings` to `off` temporarily http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS -- but if that dump comes from a different database engine, you will probably have additional problems too.

Comment: @pozs
Thank you mate :)
Yup, moving from mysql to psql :)